# Finite sum of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering if there is some chance to find a sequence of numbers $b_i,\,i=1,\ldots,n,$ such that the following conditions hold simultaneously: $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i=O(n)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n b^2_i=O(1)$. The only restriction I put is $b_i \neq 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: What about $b_i = \frac 1i$ ?

Comment: Would you clarify in what sense do you use the big O? Do you mean to find an infinite sequence $b_i$ and let $n$ be large for the partial sum?